# Save current js object in history.pushState

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

I am trying to save my current js object in history.

```
history.pushState($(this)[0],'List',window.location.href);
```

But i am getting error

> `DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned. history.pushState($(this)[0],'List',window.location.href);`

Comment: Are you sure about the `pushState` syntax?

Comment: Yeah, I got pushState from tis link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Okie dokie... I had a confusion if you are using the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

The state object can be anything that can be serialized. Because Firefox saves state objects to the user's disk so they can be restored after the user restarts the browser, we impose a size limit of 640k characters on the serialized representation of a state object. If you pass a state object whose serialized representation is larger than this to pushState(), the method will throw an exception. If you need more space than this, you're encouraged to use sessionStorage and/or localStorage.

So you are serializing with JSON.stringify for data.

```
 history.pushState(JSON.stringify($(this)[0]),'List',window.location.href);
```

Comment: it is working. But when trying to deserialize using var obj =JSON.parse(history.state). I am getting obj is null.

Comment: i can try as following code .it is working JSON.parse(history.state).so can you accept the answer if it is correct

Comment: yes yes, it is working. I forgot to do null check. Without pressing back button history.state is null. That's why I was getting null value.